# More control on SMB share connection?

Tags: network, finder, smb

Normally I would connect to a SMB share on my network using Finder.

I have found that sometimes the result is a connection to the share but my folders that I expect are not there. I suspect a miss-configuration either on the client or on the server.

As I do not have control over the server-side I would like to have more control over the connection on the client-side.

Are there ways of getting more control on the connection from the client side?

I use MacOS Sierra.

Comment: Are you sure you're not already connected to the share?  Open a Finder windows (`Shift-Cmd-H` for Home) and look at the left side under "Shared"  is your server name there?  If so, click on it to reveal the shares.

Comment: Yes, the server name is in this list and the name of the share is there but parts of the folder-structure within the share is gone, or lost. I am guessing that there is a caching issue, probably connected with a loss in connection between client and server. I look for the possibility to turn off caching, or to "reset" the connection somehow. Reconnect the share does not do a change help. Re-logon of the user-account works, but that is rather unpractical at times. Maybe I could force-kill something?

Comment: Just above the listing of folder/items, does it say "Connected as: username" and then to the right a "Disconnect" button?